# ubuntu not starting after update-grub

Tags: debian, boot, grub

I changed the default kernel in /etc/default/grub and did `update-grub`. Now every time the system is switched on, it opens BIOS settings. It's not showing any boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

`update-grub` only updates de grub configurations; you need usually to run `grub-install` after it.

The system is not booting, because grub is thus still pointing to the old kernel and not to the new one.

If you have grub in your MBR, it should have been then:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I thus advise to boot the system/VM from a live system DVD/pen/image, like Knoppix, and doing the `grub-install`